# TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. It shows the supported files are: float64, float32 etc

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

when I run this code it has a TypeError. I don't know how to solve this. please help me with this issue. and I have a question that it is running in GPU or not?

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.current_device()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
torch.cuda.memory_reserved()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
var1=torch.FloatTensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]).cuda(0)
var1
var1.device
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
df.head()
df.isnull().sum()

import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
df['Outcome']=np.where(df['Outcome']==1,"Diabetic","No Diabetic")
df.head()
sns.pairplot(df,hue="Outcome")
X=df.drop('Outcome',axis=1).values### independent features
y=df['Outcome'].values###dependent features
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
y_train
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).cuda(0)
X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test).cuda()
y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train).cuda()
y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test).cuda()
```

The error is:

---

```
C:\Users\vinot\.conda\envs\python21\python.exe D:/python/python_work/pythonProject/diabetes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/python_work/pythonProject/diabetes.py", line 35, in <module>
    y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train).cuda()
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

---

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Examine `y_train`.  `shape`, `dtype` etc

Comment: @hpaulj sorry I couldn't understand well. can you explain a little bit?  briefly

Comment: Obviously you didn't write this code yourself.  Using complex code that you don't understand is dangerous.  Either you get the inputs just right, or you get incomprehensible errors.

Comment: @anurag can you help me with an error please. what should I need to change in the following error?

Comment: `y_train` comes from `y` which is the `values` of a pandas Series (df column).  It contains strings, so is object `dtype`. You need to convert it to one of the dtypes listed in the error message.